# Gridview button configuration

Tags: android, gridview, button

I have a Gridview displaying buttons that get their content from an array, please see below:

xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@raw/br_poster_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="30dip"     >   



            <GridView android:id="@+id/brgrid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:rowHeight="90dp"
                android:numColumns="3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the java for the buttons:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        final Sample sample = board.getSamples().get(position);

        if (sample != null) {
            Button button = new Button(context);
            button.setText(sample.getName());


            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedbutton);
```

As you can see I have a custom background (transparent gradient and rounded corners), which works fine, but I'm having great difficulty changing the other properties of the button, as most of the code would usually go into xml under "Button":

For example, changing the colour of the text does not work, changing the row/column size under the GridView xml has no effect...

I would also like to have it display an evenly spaced grid with uniform button sizes instead of wrapping the text passed to the buttons and cramming them towards the top of the screen.

Is there a way I can create an xml button to be used by the Gridview?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to set the text size and layout of the button using the density scale:

```
button.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams((int)(80 * densityScale + 0.5f), (int)(50 * densityScale + 0.5f)));

button.setTextSize(12);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the need for declaring the button in the code.
Put it in de xml and set the text by retrieving the button with finViewById()

Hope this helps a bit

Comment: i see what you're getting at, this would also mean changing the way my array plays the corresponding sound files. i thought there might be a way to do it in java to save me the trouble. all i need is to change the weight and text. thanks for the help